# Recover a matrix from its Schur complements

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, schur-complement

Suppose I have a matrix:

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}A & B \\ C & D\end{bmatrix} $$

With Schur complements:

$$
M/A = D - CA^{-1}B \\
M/D = A - BD^{-1}C \\
$$

Given only the Schur complements $M/A$ and $M/D$, and the off-diagonal blocks $B$ and $C$, can I recover the original matrix $M$?  (That is, without knowing $A$ or $D$?)  It seems like this should be a lemma in a textbook somewhere, but I haven't come across it.

Note: in my actual application the matrix is symmetric positive definite such that $C=B^\top$.

**Edit**
Some resources I've looked at include [Henderson & Searles *on deriving the inverse of a sum of matrices*](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/server/api/core/bitstreams/f188acfe-950d-4973-8ca7-249c6bf846d3/content) and [Chris Yeh's blog, *Schur Complements and the Matrix Inversion Lemma*](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2021/05/19/schur-complement.html). The closest I've come is the following expressions obtained by expressing $M^{-1}$ in terms of $M/A$ and $M/D$ and then, because the matrix inverse is unique, equating the two different expressions for $M^{-1}$:

$$
(M/A)^{-1} = D^{-1} + D^{-1}C(M/D)^{-1}BD^{-1} \\
(M/D)^{-1} = A^{-1} + A^{-1}B(M/A)^{-1}CA^{-1}
$$

These at least express each of $A$ without knowing $D$ and $D$ without knowing $A$, but I still cannot figure out how to actually solve for $A$ or $D$ from the expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the matrix inversion lemma above, I think I have found an answer to my own question.  To recap, the Schur complement is traditionally used for matrix inversion.  If $A$ is invertible then it is a well-known property of the Schur complement that:

$$
M^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
A^{-1}+A^{-1}B(M/A)^{-1}CA^{-1} & -A^{-1}B(M/A)^{-1} \\
-(M/A)^{-1}CA^{-1} & (M/A)^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And if $D$ is invertible then, similarly:

$$
M^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
(M/D)^{-1} & -(M/D)^{-1}BD^{-1} \\
-D^{-1}C(M/D)^{-1} & D^{-1} + D^{-1}C(M/D)^{-1}BD^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since the matrix inverse is unique, we can set these expressions for $M^{-1}$ equal to each other to obtain the following expressions, which are commonly known as the matrix inversion lemma:

$$
\begin{gathered}
(M/A)^{-1} = D^{-1} + D^{-1}C(M/D)^{-1}BD^{-1} \\
(M/D)^{-1} = A^{-1} + A^{-1}B(M/A)^{-1}CA^{-1}
\end{gathered}
$$

Focusing on $(M/A)^{-1}$ we can left- and right-multiply by $D$, then rearrange to obtain the following.  $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix where $D$ is $n\times n$.

$$
\begin{gathered}
D(M/A)^{-1}D = DD^{-1}D + DD^{-1}C(M/D)^{-1}BD^{-1}D \\
D(M/A)^{-1}D = D + C(M/D)^{-1}B \\
0 = C(M/D)^{-1}B + D - D(M/A)^{-1}D \\
0 = C(M/D)^{-1}B + \frac{1}{2}I_nD + D\left(\frac{1}{2}I_n\right) - D(M/A)^{-1}D \\
0 = C(M/D)^{-1}B + \frac{1}{2}I_nD + D\left(\frac{1}{2}I_n\right)^\top - D(M/A)^{-1}D
\end{gathered}
$$

[James Potter](https://doi.org/10.1137/0114044) describes a method for obtaining matrix quadratic solutions.  The above can be rewritten as:

$$
0 = \mathcal{A} + \mathcal{B}X + X\mathcal{B}^\top - X\mathcal{C}X \\
$$

Where:

$$
\begin{gathered}
\underset{n\times n}{X} = D \\
\mathcal{A} = C(M/D)^{-1}B \\
\mathcal{B} = \frac{1}{2}I_n \\
\mathcal{C} = (M/A)^{-1}
\end{gathered}
$$

Then we let:

$$
\underset{2n\times 2n}{\mathcal{M}} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathcal{B} & \mathcal{A} \\ \mathcal{C} & -\mathcal{B}^\top\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}I_n & C(M/D)^{-1}B \\ (M/A)^{-1} & -\frac{1}{2}I_n\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now we can obtain the solution via the eigendecomposition of $\mathcal{M}$.  Let $\mathcal{M}$ have eigenvectors $v_i$ where each of $v_i$ is a column vector with dimensions $2n\times 1$.  We can divide each column vector $v_i$ into an upper half $u_i$ and lower halve $l_i$.

$$
v_i = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_{n} \\ v_{n+1} \\ \vdots \\ v_{2n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ \vdots \\ u_{n} \\ l_1 \\ \vdots \\ l_{n} \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then the solution will have the form:

$$
\underset{n\times n}{X} = \begin{bmatrix}u_1 & \cdots & u_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}l_1 & \cdots & l_n\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$

[Potter's paper](https://doi.org/10.1137/0114044) goes into further details about which $n$ eigenvectors to use.  In my case, the original $M$ is symmetric positive definite, which implies that $A$ and $D$ are also SPD, and so the solution $X$ must be SPD.  Under this assumption, we pick the $n$ eigenvectors $v_i$ whose eigenvalues are positive.

Note also that, if $M$ is symmetric, we can simplify the expressions for $\mathcal{M}$ by substituting $C=B^\top$.

For further intuition, consider the case where $D=d$ is scalar, in which case $B=b$ and $C=c$ are column and row vectors, respectively.  Then we would have:

$$
D(M/A)^{-1}D - D - C(M/D)^{-1}B = d^2(M/A)^{-1} - d - c(M/D)^{-1}b = 0
$$

Applying the quadratic equation:

$$
\begin{gathered}
d = \frac{-(-1) \pm \sqrt{(-1)^2-4\left[(M/A)^{-1}\right]\left[-c(M/D)^{-1}b\right]}}{2(M/A)^{-1}} \\
d = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{(1+4(M/A)^{-1}c(M/D)^{-1}b}}{2(M/A)^{-1}} 
\end{gathered}
$$

We obtain two solutions for $d$ via the $\pm$ and must carefully choose whether to add or subtract.  This is analagous to the matrix quadratic solution, in which we have a degenerate choice of which eigenvectors to use.  In the case that $M$ is symmetric positive definite, then we know that $d > 0$, $(M/A)>0$, $(M/D)$ is SPD, and we can substitute $c=b^\top$ to obtain:

$$
d = \frac{1 + \sqrt{(1+4(M/A)^{-1}b^\top(M/D)^{-1}b}}{2(M/A)^{-1}} 
$$

We recognize the quadratic form $b^\top(M/D)^{-1}b$. We know that $(M/D)$ is SPD, therefore $(M/D)^{-1}$ must also be SPD and its quadratic form $b^\top(M/D)^{-1}b > 0$. Therefore, the quantity inside the square root must be positive.  Then, by chosing to add rather than subtract, we guarantee a solution with $d > 0$.